# My blank bitmap does not appear transparent on Android phone, but does on Android emulator

Tags: android, canvas

On the emulator, newBitmap (see below) is transparent. I update newBitmap with data from another bitmap. Updated area appears whenever I call to draw newBitmap.
On the phone, I see a black screen. I set the alpha of newBitmap to 0 and it showed defaultbg. How can I achieve the same result that I get on the emulator?

background and background2 are bitmaps:

```
defaultbg = background;
newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(background2.getWidth(), background2.getHeight(), background2.getConfig());
```

I update newBitmap like this:

```
int [] pixels = new int[width * height];
background2.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, cell.getX(), cell.getY(), width, height);
newBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, cell.getX(), cell.getY(), width, height);
```

I draw them like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(defaultbg, offset, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(newBitmap, offset, 0, null);
```

Comment: Can you check background2.getPixel(x,y), to see it contains correct alpha value for certain location, and similarly newBitmap.getPixel(x,y) for same location after setting its content from background2. On phone that is, to make sure alpha values are handled properly.

Answer (score 0):

create xml file in drawable with this source

< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

```
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
```

< /shape>

then give xml file name in your layout or wherever

android:background="@drawable/kbb_border"